# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints for view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I'm loading a view controller which has a view that can take different size. The size is set in the "viewDidLayoutSubviews" and may differ regarding the parameter sent to the view.

I'm using auto-layout in my view, it consists of 2 labels under each other (title + error), a tableview, and two button side by side (confirm + cancel).

[image]

The view loads perfectly, but I still have this message:

* Xcode yelling about constraints then specify which one seem to be the problem *

`(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x604000281040 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f84ce652de0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x604000289830 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f84ce652de0.bottom == UIView:0x7f84ce66fea0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000048b630 UIButton:0x7f84ce4b3c60'Continuer'.height == 60   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002963a0 UILabel:0x7f84ce670bd0'Sexe'.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b2520'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002967b0 V:[UILabel:0x7f84ce670bd0'Sexe']-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f84ce43a770'Error']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028c4e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f84ce43a770'Error']-(5)-[UITableView:0x7f84ce850000]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028c3a0 V:[UITableView:0x7f84ce850000]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f84ce4b3c60'Continuer']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028f0a0 V:[UIButton:0x7f84ce4b3c60'Continuer']-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f84ce652de0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000048cda0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f84ce66fea0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000296670 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b2520'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f84ce66fea0 )>"
)`

Any idea what constraint is causing me such troubles ?
(I could post the full Xcode message is its of any use, but I don't want to spam.)

Comment: post the full Xcode message :)

Comment: First of all, from this log you should be able to see that the issue is on the vertical axis. Secondly, Xcode also specifies which constraints it decided to "break". The message also contains a hint of which exception you can debug, you can then look up how to find views by references from the log if manual debugging is needed. Note that the constraint that was "broken" by the layout  engine is not necessarily the one causing the problem, instead of removing it, you should analyze all constraints on the vertical axis.

Comment: I have these two:                       Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000048b630 UIButton:0x7f84ce4b3c60'Continuer'.height == 60   (active)>

---------- AND -----------                          Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028c4e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f84ce43a770'Error']-(5)-[UITableView:0x7f84ce850000]   (active)>

Comment: Hint: Whenever facing this, use: https://www.wtfautolayout.com

Comment: @Dominik It only explicitly displays the constraints :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that I was setting the height of the view after instantiating it, in the "viewDidLayoutSubviews".
I am using "Presentr" lib to instantiate a view easily.

My issue had nothing to do with constraints in the storyboard whatsoever.
I managed to fix the problem by specifying the height of my view BEFORE presenting with Presentr.
To do that, I did a protocol that forced my controller to have a "getHeight" func to get its height, allowing me to to something like that

```
let customType = PresentationType.custom(width: .custom(size: Float(self.view.frame.width)), height: .custom(size: editProfileVC.getHeight()), center: .center)
```

You can see here that, for the height, I'm using "editProfileVC.getHeight()"

I hope it can help others too.